# Command-line CSS selector tool

Tags: command-line, html, grep, web, css

## Question

What tool (preferably for Linux) can select the content of an HTML element based on its CSS path?

## Example

For example, consider the following HTML document:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <table>
      <tbody>
      <tr><td class="data">Tabular Content 1</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="data">Tabular Content 2</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What command-line program (e.g., a kind of "cssgrep") can extract values using a CSS selector? That is:

```
cssgrep page.html "body > div.content > table > tbody > tr > td.data"
```

The program would write the following to standard output:

```
Tabular Content 1
Tabular Content 2
```

## Related Links

- https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API#.24.24.28selector.29
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334942/is-there-something-like-a-css-selector-or-xpath-grep
- https://github.com/keeganstreet/element-finder
- http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/

Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the [W3C tools](http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/) for HTML/XML parsing and extraction of content using CSS selectors. For example:

```
hxnormalize -l 240 -x filename.html | hxselect -s '\n' -c "td.data"
```

Will produce the desired output:

```
Tabular Content 1
Tabular Content 2
```

Using a line length of 240 characters ensures that elements with long content will not be split across multiple lines. The `hxnormalize -x` command creates a well-formed XML document, which can be used by `hxselect`.

Comment: For macOS users, `brew install html-xml-utils`.

Comment: @dave-jarvis If I use the `hxnormalize -x` on a RSS file, I loose out the results in the end somehow : `hxnormalize -l 240 -x rss.html | hxselect -s '\n' -c 'item > link'` but if I don't `normalize` by just using a `cat rss.html | hxselect -s '\n' -c 'item > link'`, then I get all the results.

Comment: To retrieve an attribute's value, use the syntax `<node>::attr(<attribute>)`. In OP's example, `td::attr(class)` will yield `data\ndata`.

Comment: @dave-jarvis, thank you very much for the answer.  The tools are quite fantastic to use.  You can even use pseudo-classes like: `<node>.class:first-of-type`.

Answer (score 8):

## CSS Solution

The Element Finder command will partially accomplish this task:

- https://github.com/keeganstreet/element-finder
- http://keegan.st/2012/06/03/find-in-files-with-css-selectors/

For example:

```
elfinder -j -s td.data -x "html"
```

This renders the result in JSON format, which can be extracted.

## XML Solution

The [XML::Twig](https://github.com/mirod/xmltwig) module ("`sudo apt-get install xml-twig-tools`") comes with a tool named `xml_grep` that is able to do just that, provided that your HTML is well-formed, of course.

I'm sorry I'm not able to test this at the moment, but something like this should work:

```
xml_grep -t '*/div[@class="content"]/table/tbody/tr/td[@class="data"]' file.html
```

Comment: The current `elfinder` (v0.5.2) does not output the 25 results it claims to have found on my RSS file : `elfinder -s 'item > link' -f rss.html`, be it in text or JSON format.

Answer (score 8):

https://github.com/ericchiang/pup (https://github.com/htmlparser/htmlparser) has a CSS-based query language that conforms closely to your example. In fact, with your input, the following command:

```
pup "body > div.content > table > tbody > tr > td.data text{}"
```

produces:

```
Tabular Content 1
Tabular Content 2
```

The trailing `text{}` removes the HTML tags.

One nice feature is that the full path need not be given, so that again with your example:

```
$ pup 'td.data text{}' < input.html
Tabular Content 1
Tabular Content 2
```

One advantage of `pup` is that it uses the golang.org/x/net/html package for parsing HTML5.

Comment: +1 CSS selectors are more concise than xpath, though less powerful. Pup also comes packaged in a single executable.

Answer (score 2):

Node can do that with JQuery and a fake DOM.

I made a Docker image for that (https://hub.docker.com/r/phil294/jquery-jsdom/):

```
docker run --rm -i phil294/jquery-jsdom '$("body > div.content > table > tbody > tr > td.data").text()' < page.html
```

Second argument is JavaScript code, so you can do anything you want, really.